# amsengagmentd is causing a JetsamEvent due to per-process limit

Tags: iphone, ios

Every day, early in the morning, since the middle of last week, I keep getting a JetsamEvent causing by amsengagmentd due to per-process limit. Given I only have the two apps open, Signal and Whatsapp, and I wasn't using my phone at the time, how could the process be running out of memory? Why wouldn't it happen during the day?

Edit: ios version is 14.6, my phone is not jailbroken (or at least I haven't done it, and its only 3 weeks old and up to date). I can't get a screenshot right now, but as far as I can tell, it seems to be a standard JetsamEvent log, located under analytics with a listing of processes in JSON format, and only one of them with a reason, which is amsengagementd, and it is given as per-process limit. Also, I hadn't installed any new applications to cause this, and I updated to 14.6 about 18 days ago.

Edit 2: Just to add some more information, initially, the largest processes listed in the logs were Signal or Whatsapp, but for the past few days they have been either backboardd or springboard. However the reason is still listed as amsengagementd.

Edit 3: I signed out of my apple account to see if that would make a difference, and I also disabled wifi. Doesn't seem to have happened last night.

Edit 4: Signing back in immediately triggered it. All I can find is the file path for the equivalent process on macOS- /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleMediaServicesUI.framework/amsengagementd

Edit 5: Seems to be back to occurring once every few days again. Still no explanation as to why it does. Anyone else?

Comment: To add to this, the times when this happens are early mornings. However, I cannot find any info regarding why amsengagementd would cause this.

Comment: Its your device under MDM control?

Comment: No. It did seem to become more infrequent when I logged out of my apple account. It went from one every day to one every 6 days, then stopped. Then I got one as soon as I logged in again, which was a few days ago. I got another one last night.

Comment: Unlikely to add much to the discussion, but a recent run down of all DNS queries from Ventura (13.4.1) using Objective-Sea's DNSMonitor, showed the amsengagementd process resolving experiments.apple.com, the name of which suggests, well, experimentation? I believe I've got all the opt-out's switched off (privacy, analytics etc.) but who knows ‍♂️